# Why is my code displaying bizzare numbers in the output?

Tags: c, ascii

This is a program to print a histogram of the frequencies of different characters in its input. It counts uppercase and lowercase letters together.

The characters should be printed in increasing order of their ASCII value.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100], new[100];  
    int  i,j,count=0,n;
    char temp; 

    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    //convert upper chars to lower chars
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        new[i] = tolower(str[i]);

    }    

    //assign n to the length of the string
    for(j=0;new[j];j++);
    n=j; 

    //sort the string in ascending order
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (new[i] > new[j]) {
                temp = new[i];
                new[i] = new[j];
                new[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //check and print the count
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
    {
        count=1;
        if(new[i])  
        {
          for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)  
          {   
            if(new[i]==new[j])
            {
                 count++;
                 new[j]='\0';   //make the sec char 0
            }
          }  
          printf("%c %d \n",new[i],count);
       }
    } 


    return 0;
}
```

[image: Here's the output]

Comment: Compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2` to get a hint that you are calling `toupper` incorrectly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". -- Don't post text as screenshot, copy it directly, please. And if you show some code, make sure it is the one you actually use. The one you posted is it not, clearly.

Comment: If one of the answers resolved the issue, mark it as accepted so anyone else reading the question can learn from it. If the answer didn't help, maybe add a comment to indicate that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what bizarre numbers you mean from the output. All the counts of characters look correct.

If you mean the weird `1` at the start of the output, then I expect the "gotcha" is that your input (and output) includes the newline character.

> > man fgets
>
> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to
>   by  s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

So when you sort the characters, the newline character will be first.

You could solve this a few different ways, but a simple one is to only output printable characters, e.g.

```
    if(isprint(new[i]))  
        printf("%c %d \n",new[i],count);
```

Answer (score 2):

`for(j=0;new[j];j++);` fails  as `new` is not a *string*.

*null character* never assigned in `new[]` before `for(j=0;new[j];j++);`

Comment: How about I just use n = strlen(new) ?

Comment: @LPJeev `strlen(new)` expects `new` to be a _string_.  Since it is not,  `strlen(new)` is no good - undefined behavior.  Instead. make certain `new[]` has a _null character_ in the right place.

Comment: @LPJeev Think about `for(j=0;new[j];j++);`.  It should stop when `new[j] == 0`, yet prior code never sets any element of array `new[]` to `'\0'`.